# Win32 STATIC font wrong when grayed out

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, static, controls

I am working on a Win32 program and want to enable and disable my controls.
I am using the Windows XP theme and font.
When I disable a STATIC control, the used font appears to be wrong.

Enabled controls:
[image: Correct font]
Disabled controls:
[image: Wrong font]

In this image it is obvious what I mean:
[image: font detail]

This code creates the font (I found it using Google):

```
HFONT CreateControlFont( void )
{
    // Get the system message box font
    NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;
    ncm.cbSize = sizeof(ncm);

    // If we're compiling with the Vista SDK or later, the NONCLIENTMETRICS struct
    // will be the wrong size for previous versions, so we need to adjust it.
    // In versions of Windows prior to Vista, the iPaddedBorderWidth member
    // is not present, so we need to subtract its size from cbSize.
#if( WINVER < 0x0600 )
    ncm.cbSize -= sizeof(ncm.iPaddedBorderWidth);
#endif

    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, ncm.cbSize, &ncm, 0);
    return CreateFontIndirect(&(ncm.lfMessageFont));
}
```

I apply it to my controls using `SendMessage(MY_WINDOW_HANDLE, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)MY_FONT, MAKELPARAM(FALSE, 0));`.

I use this code to apply the XP style (also from the internet):

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' \
                        version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' \
                        language='*'\"")
```

This is how I create the STATIC controls:

```
HWND CreateLabel( const TCHAR * text, int x, int y, int w, int h, HMENU id, HWND parent )
{
    return CreateWindow(
        "static", text, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, x, y, w, h, parent, id, hInstance, NULL);
}
```

To disable the controls I use `EnableWindow(MY_WND_HANDLE, FALSE);`.

Now as you can see, this works as expected, except for when the control is grayed out.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You managed to write half a page without ever saying what exactly looks "wrong" to you. The controls look exactly like I would expect enabled/disabled controls to look like.

Comment: Added an image to explain. I thought it was plain to see.

Comment: I also see nothing wrong with the font even with your additional image.  The only thing I see is it appears to be a bitmap font.  Choose a vector font and it will have a much cleaner appearance.

Comment: This is just the way a STATIC control renders itself when you disable it.  If you want it to look like the other controls then you must *not* disable it and handle the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC in the dialog to change the color to gray.

Comment: This does seem to be a bug in static controls. The workaround seems to be to create a custom static control that overrides WM_ENABLE to block disabling in the normal way, instead changing the text colour, as Hans suggested.